# Best places to ride in the US

Tags: mountain-bike, road-bike, bikeroutes

What are the best places to ride in the USA? (Road and mountain)

Comment: Voting to close. Questions looking for opinion-based answers are off-topic here. Please read the relevant [Help section](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: So sorry, I just looked at others and saw stuff like "what kind of bike should I get?" and assumed that it would be okay to ask about a bike related location.

Comment: no need to apologise. It's just that this site is more about asking questions that have a definite answer, rather than a discussion forum. Hopefully you can appreciate that the "best" place to cycle will depend very much on a person's individual preferences, so such a question cannot have a "right" or "wrong" answer.

Answer (score 1):

Winter|Snow riding - Interior Alaska.
   Extended winter riding season (usually September/October through April).  Low overall snowfall meaning rides are rarely "snowed out".  Consistently low temperatures lead to trails that stay and don't melt.  High "other" traffic (snow machines, dog sleds, skijorers, cross country skiers) and large volume of trails means there is always somewhere to ride.  High population of winter bike riders for size (Alaska is arguably the birthplace of snow bike racing).

Comment: Wow, nice.... I would love to go to Alaska but my wallet highly disagrees with the idea